# How to solve this equation (find a power series)

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Please i have this equation

$$\sum_{n\geq0} n^2 a_n x^{n+1} +\sum_{n\geq0} (n-1)a_n x^n=0$$

i change $x^{n+1}$ to $x^n$ i found

$$\sum_{n\geq1} (n-1)^2 a_{n-1} x^{n} +\sum_{n\geq0} (n-1)a_n x^n=0$$

then $a_0=0$

i think that $a_1$ is trivial ?

so $\forall n\geq 2, a_{n-1}=-\frac{a_n}{n-1}$
How to continue  please ?  in order to find $a_n$

Comment: What do you mean with "solve" it? Finding the roots? Or express it in a recursive way?

Comment: find a_n @thinkingeye

Comment: You forgot to change also $n^2$ to $(n-1)^2$

Comment: oh tes i will correct it

Comment: If you cast $-a_0$ out of the second summation, then you can combine both summations into a single summation beginning with $n=2$.

Comment: I edited my question but i dont find $a_n$ such that $ a_{n-1}=-\frac{a_n}{n-1}$

Comment: @NoraNour how did you get $a_{n-1} = - \frac{a_n}{n-1}$ ?

Comment: but i find $ a_n = (n-1) a_{n-1} $ so $a_n=-n a_1$ for all $n\geq2$ with a_0=0 ans a_1 is trivial  is it right ?

Comment: $(n-1)^2 a_{n-1} = (n-1) a_n $

Comment: You should write the recursion relation in the form $a_n=-(n-1)a_{n-1}$ for $n\ge2$. This will lead to a formula for the coefficients of each $x^n$ as the product of $a_1$ and a function of $n$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Can you formulate a recursive relation just like that? The summations have different starting points...

Comment: @thinkingeye The two sums can be manipulated so that both sums begin at $n=2$. This is commonly done when finding series solutions to differential equations.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales but dont you need to move out some terms from the summation or lower the power of $x$ inside the summation?

Comment: @thinkingeye Notice that the $n=0$ term of the second sum is $0$ and so are the $n=1$ terms of both sums. So the $n=2$ term is the first non-zero term of both sums.

Comment: @thinkingeye Perhaps I should just go ahead and submit an answer.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales ah, correct, because $a_0 = 0$. I didn't see this.

Comment: i found $a_n = (-1)^{n-1} (n-1)! a_1$  it write please ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the coefficients of the power series given $a_0=0$:

$$\sum_{n\geq0} n^2 a_n x^{n+1} +\sum_{n\geq0} (n-1)a_n x^n=0$$

Replace each occurrence of $n$ in the first sum with $n-1$.

$$\sum_{n\geq1} (n-1)^2 a_{n-1} x^{n} +\sum_{n\geq0} (n-1)a_n x^n=0$$

Since the first non-zero term of both sums is when $n=2$ the sums can be combined into a single sum.

$$\sum_{n\ge2} [(n-1)^2 a_{n-1} + (n-1)a_n] x^n=0$$

Thus each coefficient equals $0$.

$$(n-1)^2 a_{n-1} + (n-1)a_n=0$$
for $n\ge2$.

This gives a recurrence relation $a_n=-(n-1)a_{n-1}$ for $n\ge2$.

So we get $a_2=-a_1$, $\quad a_3=-2a_2=+2a_1$, $\quad a_4=-3a_3=-3\cdot2\cdot1a_1$

In general we get $a_n=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!a_1$ for $n\ge2$.

Comment: that's what i found in the comments thank you very Munch

Comment: please +1 please

Comment: please can we find what is the function which is equal to $\sum_{n\geq0} (-1)^{n-1}(n-1)! a_1 x^n$

Comment: That is a power series which converges only for $x=0$, since, if $|x|\ne0$ then the series fails the ratio test for $x$. So it is equal to the function $f(x)=0$ for $x=0$ with $f(x)$ undefined for $x\ne0$.